# MATLAB rgb2hsv() vs. OpenCV cvtColor()

Tags: matlab, opencv, hsv

Has anyone else noticed that the outputs of MATLAB's [`rgb2hsv()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) and OpenCV's [`cvtColor()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) (with the argument thereof being `CV_BGR2HSV`) appear to be calculated slightly differently?

For one, MATLAB's function maps any image input to the [0,1] interval, while OpenCV maintains the same interval of the input (i.e. an image with pixels in [0,255] in RGB keeps the same [0,255] interval in HSV).

But more importantly, when normalizing the `cvtColor()` output (e.g. `mat = mat / 255`), the values are not quite the same.

I couldn't find anything in the documentations about the specific formulas they use. Can anyone please shed some light on these differences?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how big are the deviations you get?

Comment: Pretty minor...but enough that it's evident. We're talking like .04513 vs. .03777. It's enough that it could make a difference in some CV applications but not enough for basic things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OpenCV the formula is right there in the document you point to. For Matlab, have a look here http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/269237:

> Just dive into the code - they gave it to you. Just put the cursor on
>   the function rgb2hsv() in your code and type control-d.

Comment: Woops you're right about the OpenCV one...I didn't scroll far enough